# Override delete_all in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding

I want to add a `:limit` clause to `delete_all...` how can I do that?

One method I can think of is to override the default `delete_all`, but I cant get it to work... the `add_conditions!` function isn't defined!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to override anything:

```
# Rails 2
SomeModel.scoped(:limit => 10).destroy_all

# Rails 3
SomeModel.limit(10).destroy_all
```

---

**Edit:** Passing spec:

```
it "should destroy all using scope" do
  10.times { SomeModel.create }
  expect {
    SomeModel.limit(5).destroy_all
  }.to change(SomeModel, :count).by(-5)
  SomeModel.count.should == 5
end
```

Comment: i am using rails 3.0.3

the snippet still deletes all for me... Model.limit(1).delete_all

Comment: I don't know what to say - both those lines work completely as expected for me. I just wrote a spec for the rails 3 one to make sure, and it passed.

Comment: Ahhhh... it's because you're using `delete_all`. That doesn't take the scope into account (I'm guessing because it works differently to `destroy_all` - not instantiating the records first to generate callbacks). Using `destroy_all` should work using the scope.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. `destroy_all` will work with the limit, but will be slower because of the instantiation. I think that you may need to just execute the query yourself if you need to add a limit to `delete_all`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked with mysql and rails 2.3

```
# in config/initializers/active_record_extensions.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base
  # like delete_all, but honors limit (either through scope ar as a option)
  def self.delete_all_limit(conditions = nil, limit=nil, offset=nil)
    scope = scope(:find)
    sql = "DELETE FROM #{quoted_table_name} "
    add_conditions!(sql, conditions, scope)
    add_limit!(sql, {:limit => limit, :offset => offset}, scope)
    connection.delete(sql, "#{name} Delete all limited")
  end
end
```

and an even uglier hack for oracle_enhanced adpater. (I assume this is better with rails3)

```
# in config/initializers/active_record_extensions.rb

module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    # like delete_all, but honors limit and offset (either through scope ar as a option)
    def self.delete_all_limit(conditions = nil, limit=nil, offset=nil)
      scope = scope(:find)
      q = self
      limit ||= scope[:limit] if scope

      if limit
        limit = limit.to_i
         q = q.scoped(:conditions => "rownum <= #{limit}")
      end

      return q.delete_all(conditions)
    end
  end
end
```